# Get notified when the app is closed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I am using Firebase notifications to send notifications to my app which contain data that I store locally and display in a list.

When the app is open, I receive a notification and I send a broadcast to the activity that contains the list view so the data can be added to the list.

When the app is closed, I receive the notification, but the broadcast obviously isn't received by the activity. Is there a way I can be notified the next time the user opens the app that i need to add some data to the list? One way is by using local storage, but is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Local storage would be the way to go if you want to persist the data and avoid any networking calls.  You could either use a SQLite database or in `SharedPreferences` as a `json` or a `parseable/serializable` if you don't really need anything relational.  You can also use a `ContentProvider` but my impression is that might be extreme overkill here.

Since you are using firebase, you could also store the list there, and retrieve it based on some unique node identifier you give it.